# Asp.Net Mvc get image from gravatar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show user profile pic from gravatar.com like this site. In this site users change images from gravatar.com. Is there any article or tutorial about this topic.(With asp.net mvc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Google search: http://hackingon.net/post/ASPNET-MVC-Gravatar-Helpers.aspx or http://www.fatlemon.co.uk/2012/01/gravatar-htmlhelper-for-asp-net-mvc/